# NET interactive notebook, cannot use System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, jupyter-notebook, .net-6.0, dotnet-interactive, .net-interactive

I am evaluating NET interactive notebooks. I downloaded the VS code extension and created a *dib* notebook file.

Following [this](https://github.com/dotnet/interactive/blob/main/docs/nuget-overview.md) example on how to include packages, I am getting a 401 unauthenticated response when trying to use `System.Text.Json`... Tbh, I'm at a loss about what's happening. Can you make sense of it?

```cs
#r "nuget:System.Text.Json"
var t = "ttt";
var x = new { t };
System.Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(x));
```

[image]

Cheers

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-nuget-registry#authenticating-to-github-packages

Comment: Thanks, I'm still unsure on why that message pops up in the first place? I am not doing something concerning github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to install nuget for `System.Text.Json` just add `using System.Text.Json;` to the top of your file instead of nuget import:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
var t = "ttt";
var x = new { t };
Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(x));
```

Comment: This answer might be outdated, as it is no longer valid.

Comment: @MatheusRocha just spined a new .dib poliglot notebook (since . NET Interactive is now in them) and this code still works just fine no extra packages installation required.

Comment: (2,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Json' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Text' (are you missing an assembly reference?) in current C# interactive